# Handling tint color changes of UIBarButtonItems in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to change the tint color of a UIBarButtonItem. I change the tintColor property when the user makes a selection and it works just fine, but only while the user is on the current screen. Once the user pushes a new view controller onto the stack the change doesn't persist. When they go back to the screen the changed tintColor is back to the original. I have tried resetting the property in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. Still nothing. If someone could explain to me what is happening is it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
@IBOutlet var dataRunNameBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    updateUI()
}

private func updateUI() {
    equationType.text = EquationCalculator.sI.equationType
    formulaForEquation.text = EquationTableDataSource.sI.formulaText!
    self.dataRunNameBtn.title = ClipBoardModel.sI.currentDataRun.name

    // Clipboard
    if ClipBoardModel.sI.currentDataRunComputed {
        self.dataRunNameBtn.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    } else {
        self.dataRunNameBtn.tintColor = UIColor.flatSandColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind giving us some code? Could use the pertinent places where there's setup/interaction with tintColor.

Comment: Updated question with code. and could you explain what "pertinent places" is please? Thanks.

Comment: Anywhere that you're setting up or calling tintColor.

Comment: How is your model being set up? I'm curious if the value is persisting each time the model is called.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint after self.dataRunNameBtn.title is set, is the value what you're expecting?

Comment: I have a break point in that method and the green color option is getting called when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Alright, but you're saying the button isn't green there, correct? Mind sharing the button setup? (IBOutlet, etc)

Comment: Yeah exactly. Its back to the original color.

Comment: Cool. Saw this. Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19504541/4228039

Comment: Tried replacing "self.dataRunNameBtn.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()" with "UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()". Same behavior as before.

Answer (score 0):

Calling

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColorDidChange()
```

after I update by button tint color solved this problem for me!